# frac() function not returning correct value in unity/cg shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, cg

I've been playing with a noise function as part of a shader I'm using and encountered something I don't understand with regards the `frac()` function, specifically that it is returning the originally passed in number, rather than just the fractional part.

To debug the issue I created a very simple shader:

```
Shader "Custom/FracTest" {
    SubShader {
        CGPROGRAM

        #pragma surface surf Lambert
        #pragma target 3.0

        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        struct Input {
            half3 viewDir;
        };

        void surf(Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
            float4 col = 0;

            float n = 1;
            float sinn = sin(n); // ~0.84147
            float hash = sinn * 43758.5453; // ~36821.54621

            float floorHash = floor(hash); // 36821
            float fracHash = frac(hash); // should be ~0.54621

            float manualFrac = hash - floorHash;

            col.r = fracHash == hash ? 1 : 0;
            col.g = floorHash == hash ? 1 : 0;
            col.b = manualFrac == fracHash ? 1 : 0;

            o.Albedo = col.rgb;
        }

        ENDCG
    }

    Fallback "Diffuse"
}
```

As you can see, this is a Unity Surface shader, however I don't think Unity is at fault here - from looking at the generated fragment shader it hasn't messed with any of the values/datatypes around this bit of code. The values in comments are what I expect the variables to contain.

When this shader runs it simply colours the whole object based on some tests against the result of the functions. In this case my object appears red, meaning the `fracHash` value is still equal to the original `hash` value, the `floorHash` is not equal to it and the `manualFrac` value is also not equal to `fracHash` value.

I can't see what I'm doing wrong here, the documentation states there is a float variant of the `frac()` function, but I can only assume I'm just hitting some precision limit inside the `frac()` function - if I use smaller numbers it seems to return sensible results. Given it works when I manually extract the fraction, perhaps I'm using higher precision numbers?

Any ideas - am I making some wrong assumption somewhere, or am I just being an idiot :P ?

For now I'm progressing by manually calculating the fraction, but I'd like to understand what I've missed :)

Comment: I'm also getting weird results with frac. Did you find why this is happening?

Comment: Damn, years later and I'm seeing this. Anyone here know what this was? :)

Comment: Add another one to the list... I'm getting this issue 7 years after this was posted.